# How to get cell value without moving iterator forward - Excel, Java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, cell

I have problem with iteration over rows and cells in excel using java. I have data structured in sheet in this way:

[image]

I have to collect all the numbers and pass it to the constructor. I tried sth like this:

```
Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
         Row nextRow = iterator.next();
         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator(); 
         int id = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();
         int pr = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();
         int[] prId = new int[2];

         prId[0] = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();

         iterator.next(); // i have to move down one row to get 5 and 6

         precId[1] = // what should I type here?? cellIterator.next() will cause, that cell with value "5" will be omitted and I will get "6"
         int co = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();
         list.add(new Rule(id, pr, prId, co));

    }
```

How to deal with that?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I decided to get cells in other way:

```
for(int rowNum = rowStart+1; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++){
        Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        if(r == null){
            continue;
        }
        int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), 4);
        for(int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++){
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            if(c == null){
                continue;
            }else{
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

This solution is clearly better but I have problem because instead of show cells value by `System.out.println(c)` i need to pass this value to the constructor as in the example with iterators. But now i have acces to the cell using loop so i can't get value of next cell using .next() or sth similar - I can't get the next cell in one line of code, so how to create the same object as above (with iterator) but using this code?

Comment: "How to get cell value without moving forward" store the value before moving on?

Comment: @1blustone I don't know how to get this value. Read my explanation, not only a titile :)

Comment: I did, which is why I said to store it. What's the problem with the iterator moving on? Have a line like `Cell stored = cellIterator.next()` and then use that for `precId[1]`? or did I not understand properly

Comment: Instead of Iterator, why don't you read cell value directly using cell index

Comment: @1blustone When i am on cell with value 3, i have to move row down to get 5 and 6 right? so i use `iterator.next();`. Now a have to get cell with value 5 but when i call `cellIterator.next()` i wil omitt this cell and i get the cell with value 6. that is because celliteretor was pointed to a column with value 3 (this is the same column as with value 5) that's why i can't use .next() because i will loose cell with value of 5.

Comment: @pulpet112: Accepted answer is not good practice. Pleas read Busy Developers' Guide [Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells) on how to iterate over cells with control of missing / blank cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise `nextRow` variable  and `cellIterator` again -

```
Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
         Row nextRow = iterator.next();
         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator(); 
         int id = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();
         int pr = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();
         int[] prId = new int[2];

         prId[0] = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();

         nextRow = iterator.next(); // i have to move down one row to get 5 and 6
         cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
         cellIterator.next();   // for first empty cell
         cellIterator.next();   // for second empty cell

         precId[1] = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();
         int co = (int) cellIterator.next().getNumericCellValue();
         list.add(new Rule(id, pr, prId, co));

    }
```

Please note that calling `iterator.next()` again in the loop can cause some RunTimeException, it is always better to call `iterator.hasNext()` first, check the return value and then call `iterator.next()`

Comment: this should works fine but it doesnt. and i don't know why.  Looks like this iterator still omit this value...

Comment: finally it works!! I don't know why but `cellIterator.next();` should be called only once

Comment: @Vikas Sachdeva: This code is not good practice. Read [Iterate over cells, with control of missing / blank cells](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterate+over+cells%2C+with+control+of+missing+%2F+blank+cells): "The CellIterator will only return the cells defined in the file, which is largely those with values or stylings, but it depends on Excel".

Comment: @AxelRichter I am aware of this and if you see in above question comment, I suggested to read cell value directly instead of using Iterator. Since, code is currently using Iterator so I suggested solution using iterator.

Comment: @pulpet112 As suggested by AxelRichter that using Iterator is not good way. Also, you mentioned in comment that you called cellIterator.next(); only once, I think this is the difference because of using Iterator.

Comment: @VikasSachdeva Thank you so much!! I used link you provided to me, it works very very fine, records from excel are readed perfectly but in the last iteration, i recieve NullPointerException. I was wonder what should I type in this line of code : `int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);` - in place of MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT I put 4 (because I have 4 column), however, i don't really know what should be put there and i guess that this  cause the exception

Comment: @pulpet112 if you are using code mentioned in the link, then there should be no NullPointerException because code has null checks for row and cell. Regarding the value of MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT variable, it should be the count of last column that contains data. So, if your data exist till excel Column D, it should be 4, for column E, 5 and so on

Comment: @VikasSachdeva you're right, i forgot about one if-statement. But now i have another problem - how to read this cells in order to put their value to the Rule constructor?? Now I have simple loop, i cannot get next cell in one line of code...

Answer (score 0):

Other way without using Iterator -

```
    for (int rowNum = rowStart + 1; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum = rowNum + 2) {

        Row oddRow = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        if (oddRow == null) {
            continue;
        }
        int[] prId = new int[2];
        int id = (int) oddRow.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue();
        int pr = (int) oddRow.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue();
        prId[0] = (int) oddRow.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();

        Row evenRow = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        if (evenRow == null) {
            continue;
        }
        prId[1] = (int) evenRow.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
        int co = (int) evenRow.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
        list.add(new Rule(id, pr, prId, co));
```